# Sharepoint 2010 dropdown list search

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm working to create a search center in Sharepoint 2010. I was curious if its possible to have (ideally several) dropdown lists which present options and contribute to a search. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 options:

1)   Use the search refiners, though these will only appear after the initial search, and do not allow blank searches.

2)   Configure the advanced search page to allow custom modifiers.  These are found after the advanced link on the search page, and do allow blank searches.

3)    Write a custom web part that pre-caches the search refiners / custom modifiers, and shows them as potential possibilities on the default search page.  I have written one of these recently, so it is certainly possible, though it did take a bit of time and requires a supporting timer job (to determine the cached potential search options).  If you'd like to buy it from my company, I'm sure they'd be willing to sell it : )